# How to make clickable buttons for Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, button

I am making an app with *Phonegap*. Now I got buttons on my screen but nothing happens when I click them and my javascript code says it should go to another page. This is my *javascript* code, can anyone tell me what's wrong with it or how to make it work?

```
*function loadScript() {
// Wait for device to be ready loading everything
    //document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
onDeviceReady(); 
};
// When device is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById('nav1').addEventListener('mousedown', nav1Down, false);
    document.getElementById('nav1').addEventListener('mouseup',  page1Show, false);
    document.getElementById('nav2').addEventListener('mousedown', nav2Down, false);
    document.getElementById('nav2').addEventListener('mouseup',  page2Show, false);
    document.getElementById('nav3').addEventListener('mousedown', nav3Down, false);
    document.getElementById('nav3').addEventListener('mouseup',  page3Show, false);
};
// Add some GUI to the touch events
function nav1Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav1').className='down';
};
function nav2Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav2').className='down';
};
function nav3Down() {
    document.getElementById('nav3').className='down';
};
// Activate the tabs
function page1Show() {
    document.getElementById('page1').className='show';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('nav1').className='up';
};
function page2Show() {
    document.getElementById('page1').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='show';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('nav2').className='up';
};
function page3Show() {
    document.getElementById('page1').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page2').className='hide';
    document.getElementById('page3').className='show';
    document.getElementById('nav3').className='up';
};
$( document ).ready(function() {
};*
```

Comment: Did you check the device ready event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exmple code that shows how device ready event is fired.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- plugin bridge js -->
    <script src="js/device.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body on-load="initDevice()"> 
  <button>Test button</button>          
  </body>
</html>
```

in device.js

```
 //call the function when page is loaded
    function initDevice(){
       document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady(){
      alert("Device is ready");
    //call the button function 
     test();
    }
function test(){

  alert("another function call");
}
```

Note:
make sure that device ready event is fired before any device api is loaded.